# C# Method must have a return type (not void error)

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and i can't figure out this error. So help me please understand why this error appears.

```
    class test
    {
      private string z;
      private string message;

     public test()
     {
         z = "123";
         message = "qwe " + z;
     }
        public meth1() {
            return message;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(test.meth1());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Method must have a return type @ 12

Answer (score 3):

Change this `public meth1()` to this

```
public string meth1()
```

You should define a return type for your method. If you don't intent to return something, you should define it's return type to as a `void`. However, as I understand you want to return the value of `message`, which is of type `string`. Hence, you have define it's return type as `string`.

Furthermore, you have another issue with your code. This `test.meth1()` should show you an error. The method `meth1` isn't a `static` method and it shouldn't be as I understand it's purpose. This means, that you have first create an instance of an object of type `test`. I would define my type using as the first letter to be capital. It's a convention. It's not something wrong, but it is commonly used.

```
class Test
{
    private string z;
    private string message;

    public Test()
    {
        z = "123";
        message = "qwe " + z;
    }

    public Meth1() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Then you program should change like below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Here we create first an instance of our class, an object.
        var test = new Test();

        // Then we call our method.
        Console.WriteLine(test.Meth1());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're encouraging bad questions by answering them. Not to mention the constant editing (one edit every 15 seconds) just so you'd be first to get that rep.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I dissagree with your view. We don't have all the same experience, but all of us we have start from some point. If we downvote the "bad" questions, we express our power closing questions that show some effort and first of all show some piece of code, we don't help anybody to improve his/her skills.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel regarding the constant editing. Yup, that's true. I posted my initial thought and then I refined it. I don't think that this makes an answer bad or good. Of course, if something in an answer is misleading and wrong should be downvoted and the poster should be informed about his/her error. Otherwise, he will be kept in his/her ignorance, believing  wrong things to be correct and spreading them

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I have voted many times questions to be closed and I don't regret for this. Since these questions was of type: Hey how I do this? Without showing any effort. Without the questioner make any research effort. etc. Yeah in this cases we should vote to close a question.